# Perl: How to split a file

Tags: perl

I have a text file that I want to split into multiple text files using perl and output

For example:

The data starts off with:

```
[TABLE]

DATA........
DATA........

[/TABLE]

[PAGE]

[TABLE]

DATA........
DATA........

[/TABLE]
```

***Desired Output:***

File1.txt

```
DATA........
DATA........
```

File2.txt

```
DATA........
DATA........
```

So basically anything in between `[TABLE]` & `[/TABLE]` should be a new text file and so forth. And the naming convention for the new text files can be File1.txt, File2.txt, etc…

Please point me in the right direction.

Thanks for all your help.

```
 #!usr/bin/perl
 my $fi, $fi2;
 my $line;
 my $i;
 my @lines;
 my @filenameparts;
 my $filename = "file1.txt";

 open($fi, "< complex.txt");
 @lines = <$fi>;
 open ($fi2, " > $filename");

 foreach (@lines)
 {
    if (($i > 0) and $_ =~ /[TABLE]/)
 {
            @filenameparts = split("_", $filename);
            foreach (@filenameparts)
            {

             print "-----------------------------\n";
             print .$_;
             print "-----------------------------\n";               
            }
            @filenameparts[1] = substr(@filenameparts[1], 0,            @filenameparts[1].length() - 5);
            @filenameparts[1] = ($filenameparts[1] + 1);
            $filename = @filenameparts[0]."_".@filenameparts[1].".txt";
            print $filename;
            close($fi2);
            open ($fi2, " > $filename");
            $i = 0;
            print $fi2 $_;

    }
    else
    {
         print $fi2 $_;
    }
    $i++;

}
```

Comment: I have tried this code above and it only allows me to break into 5 text files when I am expecting 10. In addition, would there be a more efficient way and shorter code to achieve same objective. Regards.

Comment: First off, always ``use strict;`` and ``use warnings;`` in the start of your script. It seems that your way of deciding what file to write to is very complicated. Just use a counter (call it ``$j``) and ``open($fi2, '>', "File$j.txt");`` when you need to open the next file.

Comment: There's no need to slurp the file into the array...there really isn't.

Answer (score 1):

How is this,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ':5.10';
while ( defined( my $_ = <DATA> ) ) {

  my ( $start_tag, $end_tag );
  if ( index($_,'[TABLE]') != -1 ) {
    $start_tag = 1;
  }
  elsif ( index($_,'[/TABLE]') != -1 ) {
    $end_tag = 1;
  }

  if ( $start_tag .. $end_tag ) {
    state $fileno //= 1;
    state $fh_gen = sub {
      state $fh;
      return $fh if defined $fh;
      open ( $fh, '>', "file_$fileno.txt" ) or die $!;
      $fh;
    };

    if ( $start_tag ) {}
    elsif ( $end_tag ) {
      $fileno++;
      $fh_gen = sub {
        state $fh;
        return $fh if defined $fh;
        open ( $fh, '>', "file_$fileno.txt" ) or die $!;
        $fh;
      };
    }
    else {
      my $fh = $fh_gen->();
      print $fh $_;
    }

  }

}

__DATA__

[TABLE]

DATA........
DATA........

[/TABLE]

[PAGE]

[TABLE]

DATA........
DATA........

[/TABLE]
```